# A "double call" to the constructor of an object is acceptable

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Guys to my surprise i see that a "double call" to the constructor of an object is acceptable by the compiler. Any idea what purpose does this serve and what would be the result of such a function?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vLabel : Tlabel;
begin
  vLabel := Tlabel.Create(self).Create(self);
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're surprised. `TLabel.Create(Self)` returns an instance of `TLabel`, and a `TLabel` has a method named `Create`, so you can call it. :-) You can also use something like `TLabel.Create(Self).Free`, not that it would make any sense in this case.

Comment: To be honest, I was also quite surprised when I found out that "Constructor chaining" is entirely legal in Delphi. Tutorials often don't mention it.

Comment: it is odd, because Create is a class method, you are certainly loosing memory

Comment: @Qsebas, no you're not. The above snippet does not create two labels.

Comment: @Qsebas: No, there's no leak (at least as far as the memory manager's `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown` can tell, anyway).

Comment: There is no leak because of the owner parameter. `vLabel := TLabel.Create(nil).Create(nil); vLabel.Parent := Self;` leaks

Comment: There is no leak in this particular case, but there could be in another one. If you have an object instantiated by the `Create` method, the second call will create a second instance without freeing the first one, which usually only happens in the `Destructor` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second call to `Create` works like a regular procedure call: it omits any of the special construction code and only performs the user code in the constructor. In practice this is very useful to be able to call other constructors from the implementation of a constructor:

```
constructor TLabel.CreateHello(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  // Perform default construction.
  Create(AOwner);
  // Set default text.
  Caption := 'Hello';
end;
```

Compare this to C++ where you have to move shared logic for multiple constructors to a separate function because you can't call a constructor once the object has been created. The Delphi solution is elegant and encourages code reuse.

To implement this, there is a hidden extra boolean parameter for constructors that specifies whether to perform full construction logic (e.g. memory allocation) or not.

Comment: Also note that `Create(AOwner)` neither has to be the first operation in this constructor, neither the only overloaded constructor that is being called. Java for example has this limit.

Comment: FYI, C++11 introduces delegating constructors, so that a constructor can call another constructor of the same class, and thus shared logic does not have to be separated out anymore.

Comment: @Frederik I'm not so sure it's the most elegant solution. Separation of object instantiation in the Delphi object model into creation and initialization procedures would be simpler and clearer. Here we're seeing magic/hidden/astonishing behavior.

Comment: Remy: Thanks, I didn't know that. alcalde: In practice it doesn't lead to problems.